# Avoiding "Error: Calling convention doesn't match forward" in FPC mode

Tags: freepascal

```
unit Unit1;

{$MODE FPC}
{$MODESWITCH REPEATFORWARD OFF} // doesn't make the error go away

interface

procedure test_proc;stdcall;

implementation

procedure test_proc;//stdcall;
begin
// whatever
end;

end.
```

The previous unit will not compile unless I uncomment the "stdcall;" on the implementation of the procedure. If I switch to {$MODE DELPHI} this will work just the same as if I uncomment the implementation stcall but I was wondering if it is possible to omit the stdcall on implementation while in {$MODE FPC}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`parser messages`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userse62.html#x175-182000C.3) section in documentation is quite clear about this problem (emphasized by me):

> **Error: Calling convention doesn’t match forward**
>
> This error happens when you declare a function or procedure with e.g.
>   cdecl; but omit this directive in the implementation, or vice versa.
>   **The calling convention is part of the function declaration, and must be repeated in the function definition.**

This is required by the compiler parser with no workaround (except using `{$MODE DELPHI}`, as you've already mentioned). In the pdecsub.pas unit, from where this error comes from, is this block (formatted, shortened and commented by me):

```
// this compares calling conventions in the declarative and implementation parts; if
// the conventions differ, then...
if (fwpd.proccalloption <> currpd.proccalloption) then
begin
  // if {$MODE DELPHI} is used, then...
  if (m_delphi in current_settings.modeswitches) then
  begin
    // if the implementation part of the function doesn't contain calling convention
    // then assign it the one from the declarative part
    if not (po_hascallingconvention in currpd.procoptions) then
      currpd.proccalloption := fwpd.proccalloption
    else
    // otherwise check if the declarative part has calling a convention and if not,
    // assign it the one from the implementation part
    if not (po_hascallingconvention in fwpd.procoptions) then
      fwpd.proccalloption := currpd.proccalloption
    else
    // this smells like dead code, because how could calling conventions differ but
    // neither declarative nor implementation part of a function would have calling
    // convention specified ?
    begin
      // this returns 'Calling convention doesn't match forward' for {$MODE DELPHI}
      MessagePos(currpd.fileinfo, parser_e_call_convention_dont_match_forward);
      tprocsym(currpd.procsym).write_parameter_lists(currpd);
      currpd.proccalloption := fwpd.proccalloption;
    end;
  end
  else
  // mode other than {$MODE DELPHI} is used...
  begin
    // this returns 'Calling convention doesn't match forward' with no mercy
    MessagePos(currpd.fileinfo, parser_e_call_convention_dont_match_forward);
    tprocsym(currpd.procsym).write_parameter_lists(currpd);
    currpd.proccalloption := fwpd.proccalloption;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: But if I use {$MODE DELPHI} then I don't need to repeat the calling convention on the implementation of the function. I suspect there's a switch to add this nice convenience to {$MODE FPC} and {$MODE OBJFPC} but I tried a whole bunch of them without success.

Comment: The error comes [`from here`](https://github.com/graemeg/freepascal/blob/master/compiler/pdecsub.pas#L3193) if mode is other than `{$MODE DELPHI}` and it's a [`simple comparison`](https://github.com/graemeg/freepascal/blob/master/compiler/pdecsub.pas#L3170) if the calling conventions matches in the interface and implementation sections. I don't know what the `REPEATFORWARD` switch should have been for, but it doesn't affect that parsing stage at all (at this time). That comparison code block is the only place from where this error message is returned, so you're out of luck here.

Comment: I've included and commented excerpt from the source. As you may see, mode other than `{$MODE DELPHI}` has no chance to have different calling conventions in declarative and implementation part of the function.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, I see you're right and will accept your answer.